# MySQL root problems (using mysqlworkbench accidently revoked root's access)

Tags: mysql, root

please help!...

I am facing a huge problem..i had access to mysql database through MySQL workbench but one of my coworkers accidentally went on to **users and privileges and revoked something for something...he thought he was deleting another user.**

Now I can't access my database on mysql workbench and all my privileges are gone....i am able to login to mysql on bash via 
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p

but i can't seem to add or get my privileges back......i am logging through root on terminal...also my website is down because of this.
test 1:

```
         mysql> show grants for 'root';
         ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'root' 
         on host '%'
         mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
      +--------------------------------------------------------------+
      | Grants for root@localhost |
      +--------------------------------------------------------------+
      | GRANT USAGE ON . TO 'root'@'localhost' |
      | GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
      +--------------------------------------------------------------+
      2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

**test 2:
mysql> select host, user from mysql.user;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user'
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, GRANT, REFEREN CES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, TRIGGER command denied to user 'root' @'localhost' for table '*'**
```

also I have no privileges, it seems.

```
          mysql> CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
          ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the 
          CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation
```

[also there doesn't seem to be any grant here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7rhk.jpg)

Please help, I have no access to my database and my website is down..

Comment: [similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables)

Comment: Hi @Wumpus,even after stopping mysql and restarting with skipping grant tables it still asks for password? also running the command show databases, i get only information schema and nothing else..all the other privileges are still; denied..please help...i'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Like [mysql manual reset permissions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)(adjust URL to server version). Instead of `ALTER USER` / `SET PASSWORD` you'd need `CREATE USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "password"; GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION` in the text file as your root user has been removed. Also recommend creating another user for your trusty co-workers to use instead of root.